# Date insert through parameter in Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle

I am setting up a stored procedure in oracle. which accepts many parameters. Several of them are of "date" type.

In my application I check a value and assign default value if it meets a certain criteria like this:

```
private static string FixInputString(string s)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? "-1" : s;
}
```

Then, I format it as a date for Oracle

```
private static string ConvertToOracleDate(string s)
{
    var temp = string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) || string.Equals(s, "-1", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        ? "01-Jan-1900" : Convert.ToDateTime(s).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    return temp;
}
```

When I run it, I have this value in the variable:

[image]

Then I setup parameters as such:

```
new SpParameterOracle
{
    Key = "p_SGND_DT",
    Value = ConvertToOracleDate(FixInputString(form.SignedOnDate)),
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
    Type = OracleDbType.Date
},
```

Here is the content of the parameter as it is when I am assigning it to OracleCommand:
[image]

My stored procedure, processes the input parameter as such:

```
decode(TO_CHAR(p_SGND_DT, 'mm/dd/yyyy'), '01/01/1900', null, TO_DATE(p_SGND_DT, 'DD-MON-YYYY')),
```

I also tried this:

```
decode(TO_CHAR(p_SGND_DT, 'mm/dd/yyyy'), '01/01/1900', null, p_SGND_DT),
```

The resulting value in the table is this:

[image]

Why did it change from 01-Jan-1901 to 01-Jan-2001 ???

So far, I have tried toggling formats both in the application and in the stored procedure, result is still the same.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

---

As it was suggested in one of the answers, conversion is the culprit of this issue.

Instead of dealing with it, i have modified logic of the stored procedure as well as the code.
In the stored procedure i made all necessary fields optional like this:

```
p_SGND_DT in date default null,
```

Then i simply insert a value into the table.
On the application side, i have modified code to send only parameters which are used and omit the rest, which are null.

Thanks for helping and pointing me in the right direction. Much appreciated.

Comment: Did you just try calling the stored proc from sqlplus and see what the results are?

Comment: No, but i will do it now...

Comment: It was not happy about format: 'dd-MON-yyyy'. Changed to 'dd/MM/yyyy'. Result same: '1/1/2001'.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because of the `TO_DATE(p_SGND_DT, 'DD-MON-YYYY')` in your stored procedure. `p_sgnd_dt` is a DATE datatype (or so you have implied), therefore there is no need to try and convert it into a date again.

You should only ever use to_date on something that is a string.

If you do TO_DATE() on something that is already a date, what happens is that Oracle has to do an implicit conversion of the date back to a string before turning it back into a date again. Therefore your `TO_DATE(p_SGND_DT, 'DD-MON-YYYY')` actually becomes:

`TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(p_SGND_DT, <nls_date_format parameter>), 'DD-MON-YYYY')`

The default nls_date_format is 'DD-MON-YY', meaning that you have now lost the first two digits of the year, and when Oracle tries to convert it back to a four digit year, it guesses what the first two digits will be - and gets them wrong.

I'm not sure why you're converting your parameter into a string to do the comparison in the first place, though - it would be better as:

`decode(p_SGND_DT, to_date('01/01/1900', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), null, p_SGND_DT)`

or, if you are trying to remove any time element from the date passed in:

`decode(p_SGND_DT, to_date('01/01/1900', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), null, trunc(p_SGND_DT))`

Comment: Agreed. but even if i do drop second 'to_date' it still the same. 1/1/2001

Comment: can you supply the specification of your procedure please? Ie. the bit which tells you the information about expected parameters etc.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? Do you want to see the whole procedure?

Comment: Ideally, yes, but at least the bit that is the spec - eg create or replace procedure proc_name (param1 in date, ....)